# Android opengl coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es

I recently started using openGL, because canvas in normal view was no longer powerful enough for my needs. But i cant seem to understand the coordinates system in opengl though.

When i make a rectangle with bottom coordinates y=0, i get a result of a rectangle in the top half of the screen. That is expectable.

But, when i set y=0.25f, well i would expect that the rectangle would be a quarter top of the screen. But in reality its less, something like 1/6 or 1/7.

Or when i tried y=0.375f (should be 1/8 of screen), the result is something like 1/11 or 1/12. Can some1 explain why that happens? What am i missing. And how then can i make a rectangle that fills the top 1/8 of the screen?

(I know that the top of the screen and bottom have -+0.5f coordinates at the zoom im in)

Answer (score 3):

This could be caused by the position of your camera from your View matrix. 
Recall the orientation of the coordinate system in OpenGL:

- +x points right
- +y points up
- +z points out of the screen
- (0,0,0) is in the center of the screen

To set up the camera:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0f); 

// My camera is located at (0,0,2),
// it's looking toward (0,0,0)
// its top is pointing along (0,1,0) aka. Y-axis.
```

If my rectangle is somewhere on the XY-plane, meaning the Z-coordinate is 0, then my camera is 2 units away from it on the positive Z-axis. Viewing the rectangle from this position makes it look smaller than expected. To make the rectangle look bigger, try moving the camera closer to it by changing its location in the view matrix. I changed the Z-coordinate from 2 to 1 below:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0f); 

// My camera is located at (0,0,1),
// it's looking toward (0,0,0)
// its top is pointing along (0,1,0) aka. Y-axis.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code samples from the example:

[Android Training > Applying Projection and Camera Views](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection.html#camera-view)

1. *Define a Camera View*

   ```
   // Set the camera position (View matrix)
   Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

   // Calculate the projection and view transformation
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
   ```

   Produces in my case a coordinate system with y-axis range from -1 to +1.
2. *Define a Projection*

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
       GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

       float ratio = (float) width / height;

       // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
       // in the onDrawFrame() method
       Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
   }
   ```

   Corrects the window proportions